# how do I view my meteor.js setup on ubuntu remotely?

Tags: meteor, ping

I'm looking to test meteor.js on ubuntu remotely but my browser does not connct. the ip is good and so is the port.

Comment: hmm ping does not seem to be working. I'm running ubuntu via amazon (ec2). this seems to grant ping but I'm still unable to get at the default port for meteor :3000

Comment: Try switching off iptables to test if its on `service iptables stop` also check your EC2 Security group that it allows duplex tcp connections on port 3000 for any ip address

Comment: still unable to connect http://ec2-50-19-180-244.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/

Comment: Is port 3000 allowed in your firewall rules? http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/. If it is allowed, It would be good if you take two minutes to list out the stuff you have tried so we won't have to ask you stupid questions :)

Comment: I can't ping. I set to default security group. what step should I take to have ping and a web server on port 3000

Comment: @mubix can  you help out further? I can't ping. I set to default security group. what step should I take to have ping and a web server on port 3000

Comment: You don't need ping .. just add port 3000 TCP to the default security group and it should work.

Comment: didn't work :-(  http://ec2-54-234-213-107.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/  note that I'm using http://docs.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an issue with Meteor. I have Meteor working fine on EC2. Most likely it's an issue with the default AWS security groups blocking port 3000. You need to go in there and enable access to that port.

Comment: Yes I opened port 3000 and  still an issue. good to meet someone who is implementing the same meteor stack. do you have any posts/articles/tutorials about your meteor experience?

Comment: For the most part it just works out of the box. Haven't run any issues that are specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: how do i get the public key after establishing an ec2 instance